# VB.NET Get list of keys from json deserialized object

Tags: json, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I want to get the keys present in a json deserialized object

The json looks like :

```
{"key1":1,"key2":2,"key3":3}
```

I'm using JavaScriptSerializer :

```
Dim jsonStr As String = "{""key1"":1,""key2"":2,""key3"":3}"

Dim j As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(jsonStr)

Dim jQty As Integer = j.Count 'Count key/value pairs (Return 3)
```

Now I want to get the list of existing keys in j.
I tried :

```
Dim keys As List(Of String) = j.Properties().Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToList()
```

But it gave me "System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Properties' on type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' not found.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it is deserializing into a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` object, as the error message says.  Therefore, you just need to loop through the list of dictionary entries:

```
For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In j
    Console.WriteLine("Key = " & entry.Key)
    Console.WriteLine("Value = " & entry.Value)
Next
```

Or, if you just need the key names:

```
j.Select(Function(entry) entry.Key)
```